# All string list to a numpy float array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am reading a csv file from pandas where I have a column of (3,3) shaped lists.
An example list is as follows.

```
[[45.70345721, -0.00014686, -1.679e-05], [-0.00012219, 45.70271889, 0.00012527], [-1.161e-05, 0.00013083, 45.70306778]]
```

I tried to convert this list to a numpy float array with `np.array(arr).astype(np.float)`. But it gives the following error.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

When I searched for the root cause I observed that this list is in fully string format. `print [i for i in arr]` gives the following where everything is a string.

```
['[', '[', '4', '5', '.', '7', '0', '3', '4', '5', '7', '2', '1', ',', ' ', '-', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '4', '6', '8', '6', ',', ' ', '-', '1', '.', '6', '7', '9', 'e', '-', '0', '5', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '-', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '2', '1', '9', ',', ' ', '4', '5', '.', '7', '0', '2', '7', '1', '8', '8', '9', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '5', '2', '7', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '-', '1', '.', '1', '6', '1', 'e', '-', '0', '5', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '3', '0', '8', '3', ',', ' ', '4', '5', '.', '7', '0', '3', '0', '6', '7', '7', '8', ']', ']']
```

How do I convert this list to a numpy float array?

**EDIT**

Here is a snap of a part of my data frame.
 [image]

When loaded, the data frame is in the below format. `df` here is a small example data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["e_total"], data=[[['[', '[', '4', '5', '.', '7', '0', '3', '4', '5', '7', '2', '1', ',', ' ', '-', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '4', '6', '8', '6', ',', ' ', '-', '1', '.', '6', '7', '9', 'e', '-', '0', '5', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '-', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '2', '1', '9', ',', ' ', '4', '5', '.', '7', '0', '2', '7', '1', '8', '8', '9', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '5', '2', '7', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '-', '1', '.', '1', '6', '1', 'e', '-', '0', '5', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '3', '0', '8', '3', ',', ' ', '4', '5', '.', '7', '0', '3', '0', '6', '7', '7', '8', ']', ']']]])
```

Could someone give it a try and help me to convert this to a float array.

Comment: Is the list actually named `list`? That's a big no-no

Comment: @CharlesLandau No, `type(arr)` yields `<type 'str'>`

Comment: Having a variable `list` is the part that's not allowed. `list` is already a Python object

Comment: @ Charles means is the name you assigned to the variable `list`

Comment: based on what you are putting you actually have a string representation of a python list.  

so you really have is

"[[45.70345721, -0.00014686, -1.679e-05], [-0.00012219, 45.70271889, 0.00012527], [-1.161e-05, 0.00013083, 45.70306778]]"

notice the quotes.

Comment: @FChm Sorry it was originally `arr`. I changed it when posting here. Edited the question.

Comment: The comment of @bravosierra99 comment is probably true.

Comment: @bravosierra99 Correct. Is there a way to convert this to a numpy float array that I want?

Comment: erm, maybe, but perhaps you should look into why it's a giant string.  Are you doing any preprocessing?  Can you share more of your code?

Comment: It would be much better, if it were not a string

Comment: Let me update the question with an example dataframe and the code.

Comment: updated my answer, please see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use eval() to turn the entire string into an actual list.  eval() is generally not good to use, but in this case it might be your best bet.

What you listed as your "example" is not correct.  You are listing the result of your print statement and list comprehension.  What is being stored as an entry for that column is a string.

you should be able to simply take each item and wrap it in eval

```
eval(arr)
```

that should return you a shape (3,3) python list.  From there you can convert it to a numpy array as necessary and change the types.

Comment: Oh yes this works, thanks! Yeah I couldn't generate the exact raw string in python, one would rather have to load it from the file.

Comment: @avin sure thing.  So just to be clear, using eval is HIGHLY discouraged.  I'm sure you can google a lot of reasons why.  I would not put it in any production code or become reliant on it if you can help it.  thanks for accepting and upvoting my solution.  A lot of people don't take the time!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the numbers in the lists already floats? If that is the case just making the list an np.array will do what you are asking. You only need to do

np.array(list)

if the numbers are actually strings like you are showing in the second part you will have to go through the list and convert each number individually using either a nest loop or nested list comprehension.

the loop looks like this

for i in list:

```
for j in i:

    j= np.float(j)
```

the list comprehension looks like

new_list= [ [np.float(j) for j in i] for i in list]

Comment: it's possible we were talking while you were typing up your answer, but you should read the comments above.

Comment: @D.sanders Unfortunately this doesn't work because of the format of the list. I have updated the question.